# How to check if a user nickname contains some specific letters (DISCORD.JS)?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I just want to know to check a user nickname, if it contains some specific characters. Thank you.

The important part of the code is here

```
let member = message.guild.members.cache.get(message.author.id)
if(!message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "Member")){ 
return message.channel.send("You need to have a role to change your name symbols!")
}

if (message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "Test")) {
      if(member nickname contains specific characters){ 
//Obviously this is the line I want to know how to do 
         return message.channel.send("Your name symbols are good already.")
      }
      member.setNickname(`÷${member.nickname}÷`);
 }
```

Also remember that is a little part of the code, not the whole code, so don't say that I missed some `}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what symbols you want to check so I used `/` and `!`.

```
let member = message.guild.members.cache.get(message.author.id)
if (!message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "Member")) {
  return message.channel.send("You need to have a role to change your name symbols!")
}

if (message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "Test")) {
  if (member.nickname.toLowerCase().includes('!') || member.nickname.toLowerCase().includes('/')) {
    return message.channel.send("Your name symbols are good already.")
  }
  member.setNickname(`÷${member.nickname}÷`);
}
```

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted so other people who need help with this can find this.